# Problema con retorno de lista en Ruby

Tags: ruby

tengo que hacer que mi código retorne una lista, pero agregándole comillas y espacios entre las palabras.

```
module DiscoCompilado
  @canciones = [AmorAusente, Eco, Agujas, ElBalcon, GuitarrasDeCarton]
  
  def self.nombres_de_canciones
    @canciones.each {|una_cancion|@canciones.map}
  end
end

(lo que debería retornar es ["Amor Ausente", "Eco", "Agujas", "El Balcon", "Guitarras De Carton"]
```

Comment: Pero AmorAusente, etc... que son? clases? variables?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás utilizando el método `each`, cuando me parece que estás intentando usar el método `map` (que retorna una lista modificada).

Más allá de eso, si lo que querés es armar una cadena (string) con los elementos de la lista el método que querés es `join`:

```
@canciones.join(" ") #=> "Amor Ausente Eco Agujas El Balcon Guitarras De Carton"
```

Si por otro lado, no querés una gran cadena si no una lista (como planteas en la pregunta) el método que necesitas es `inspect`.

```
@canciones.inspect #=> ["Amor Ausente", "Eco", "Agujas", "El Balcon", "Guitarras De Carton"]
```